# grep does not finish the process (Killed: 9)

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I have two files: 
`toDelete.txt` with round about 50k IDs
`Alles.txt` with round about 200k IDs + further information

I want a third file (`FOO.txt`) with 150k IDs + further information.

My code:

```
grep -vFf toDelete.txt Alles.txt > FOO.txt
```

At the end I have `FOO.txt` with round about 4k Entries and in Terminal the Message `Killed: 9`:

```
grep -vFf toDelete.txt Alles.txt > FOO.txt
Killed: 9
```

Comment: Have you tried building `grep` from source code?

Comment: Also you could try `sudo dtruss grep -vFf toDelete.txt Alles.txt > FOO.txt` , but you would need to turn off SIP. This would yield you system calls tracking and perhaps give some insight on what's failing.